# What could stop a mailing from being sent?

Tags: civimail

When I submit a mailing (as administrator), it works correctly. When another user (WP editor) does it, the mailing didn't get sent. There was nothing unusual in the cron job log as far as I could see. I didn't find any special settings in the privileges list.

Where should I look?

Comment: sounds odd. assuming this isn't permission related as 'wp editor' wouldn't be getting to where they can submit. are you certain the Scheduled Job is set to run? (trying to think of obvious things to double check)

Comment: The obvious things are OK. I'll look more carefully next month when the secretary tries to submit the mailing again ;-)